# Use Text-to-speech Azure service on public SPA (no authentication)

Tags: azure, azure-functions, single-page-application, api-key, azure-cognitive-services

I have a public SPA website (written in Svelte), with **no user authentication**.

I'd like to use the **Azure Text-to-speech service** (as either REST Api or with the azure-cognitive-services npm package).

I now need to provide the **api key** to use the service... But I understand it is a bad practice to store that key in the client code.

What would be the way to use that service then?  Do I really need a backend service?  Do I need to wrap my text-to-speech code in something like an Azure Function?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

- If you look at the [Source Code](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/blob/master/quickstart/javascript/node/text-to-speech/index.js) of the `microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk`  NPM package it is clear the only way to auth to the service is by using some form of token/id which you will have to store at client side.
- Instead of that you can use an azure function which will take text and convert to text .

My index,js file in azure function .

```
var  t = require('./test');
var  fs = require('fs');
module.exports = async  function (context, req) {
    const  name = (req.query.name || (req.body && req.body.name));
    t(name);
    context.res = {
        body:""
    }
}
```

The main processing will be in the file `test.js`

```
function  test (text) {
    var  sdk = require("microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk");

    var  readline = require("readline");
    // This will be the name of the file  created later 
    var  audioFile = "YourAudioFile.wav";
    const  speechConfig = sdk.SpeechConfig.fromSubscription(process.env.SPEECH_KEY, process.env.SPEECH_REGION);
    const  audioConfig = sdk.AudioConfig.fromAudioFileOutput(audioFile);
    speechConfig.speechSynthesisVoiceName = "en-US-JennyNeural";
    var  synthesizer = new  sdk.SpeechSynthesizer(speechConfig, audioConfig);
    synthesizer.speakTextAsync(text,

function (result) {

if (result.reason === sdk.ResultReason.SynthesizingAudioCompleted) {

console.log("synthesis finished.");

} else {

console.error("Speech synthesis canceled, " + result.errorDetails +

"\nDid you set the speech resource key and region values?");

}

synthesizer.close();

synthesizer = null;

},

function (err) {

console.trace("err - " + err);

synthesizer.close();

synthesizer = null;

});
}
module.exports = test ;
```

Majority of code from above is from the [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/get-started-text-to-speech?tabs=windows,terminal&pivots=programming-language-javascript#synthesize-to-file-output)

- At the end all you have to do is return the file created by the synthesizer.